# String! does not conform to protocol 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I am trying to use a method that was defined as Objective C method, from a swift file

the method in objective c is defined as

```
-(instancetype) init:(NSString*)string data:(id)data;
```

the method name cannot be refactored.

I am trying to invoke it as follows

```
let myObject = MyObject("MyString",data:["1","2","3"])
```

in return i am getting the compile error : "`String! does not conform to protocol 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'`"

How can I fix it?

EDIT:

MyObject is defined as follows

```
`@interface MyObject<__covariant Type> : NSObject @end

@implementation

@end`
```

Comment: I have copied both your Objective-C definition and the Swift code in an Xcode 8 project, and it compiles without problems.

Comment: What is being done inside the constructor?

Comment: self.string = string;
self.data = data;

Comment: @MartinR could you paste the way you invoked the object constructor ?

Comment: Exactly like you did: `let myObject = MyObject("MyString",data:["1","2","3"])
`.

Comment: Does your `MyObject` have any other initializers?

Comment: @OOPer yes it does, it has 3 more initializers like the one mentioned above `init:(NSString *)string data:(id)data block:(blockdef) block`

Comment: Seems checking overloads is not needed in your case. With your edited question, I can reproduce the same result. In Swift 3, ObjC generics are imported as Swift generics. And you always need to specify the type parameter in Swift generics. (And Swift 3 is not yet so refined as to generate appropriate diagnostics...) Try `let myObject = MyObject<NSString>("MyString",data:["1","2","3"])` (replace `NSString` to any other proper concrete type) .

Comment: @OOPer it forces me to do `let myObject = MyObject<NSString>("MyString",data:["1","2","3"]) as! MyObject<AnyObject>!`
Why ?

Comment: With your code shown above, I am not forced to use ` as! MyObject<AnyObject>!`. Other parts still hidden may be affecting.

Comment: @OOPer please post your previous comment as an answer, and I will accept it as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: If some part of my comments helped you solve the issue, I believe you can write an answer by yourself. Please take sometime to post it and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, ObjC generics are imported as Swift generics. And you always need to specify the type parameter in Swift generics. (And Swift 3 is not yet so refined as to generate appropriate diagnostics...)

```
let myObject = MyObject<NSString>("MyString",data:["1","2","3"])
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data actually data, or a [String]?

Comment: for testing purposes it is [String] , for other purposes it is a more complex object.